# Bitdefender Free Antivirus Detected an Injection: Injection was being performed by OpenWith.exe

Tags: windows, anti-virus, notepad, windows-11, bitdefender

I was just trying to open a .txt file and when I clicked on it, it asked me to choose a program to open the file with. I clicked on the app and the box disappeared. I tried it multiple times and after 4 times, I could finally set Notepad as my default .txt file editor. But when I looked at the log of Bitdefender, it said it had blocked an Injection with the message below:

```
Injection detected as Gen:Variant.Bulz.185472 was performed by C:\Windows\System32\OpenWith.exe and was blocked. Your device is safe.
```

Is it a false positive? Or is it something else? By the way, I'm using Windows 11.

**UPDATE**: I also did a C Drive scan, and it detected nothing suspicious.

**UPDATE 2**: Bitdefender logged the injection each time I clicked the file and tried to set the default viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested my own `C:\Windows\System32\OpenWith.exe` with
[Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)
and it generated
[this report](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f2db6838b734264fab79d24e5f96a21e6528073360a8daaa8d7efb8bc5d5edb4),
where none of the antivirus engines detected it as a virus,
*including BitDefender*.
You could verify that you're using the latest virus definitions
and try again.

If the problem isn't solved by the latest virus definitions,
I suggest to use Virus Total to upload and test your own
`OpenWith.exe`. If you get the same results as me, then this
is just a false positive.

However, if any one engine found it as infected, then see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Note: In case the above error is misleading, it's possible that
BitDefender is not detecting `OpenWith.exe` as a virus, but rather
the application you're using to open the file with.
So test this application in the same way.